# DML not allowed on Profile error message

Tags: apex, unit-test, profile

I created a test using the following apex code:

```
static testMethod void testProfile() {

    Test.startTest();

    Task task = [select id, OwnerId from task where OwnerId = '00104'];

    Profile p = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator'];

    User u = new User(alias = 'salesf', email='iamasalesforce@noemail.com', timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', localesidkey='en_US', emailencodingkey='UTF-8', ProfileId = p.Id, Id = task.OwnerId, languagelocalekey='en_US', lastname='Testing', Firstname='Testing', CompanyName= 'xyz', username='iamasalesforce@noemail.com');
    insert u;

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

but I recevied the following error message:

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

How can I execute the code in my tets method without receiving such error message?

Comment: Profile cannot be inserted from code. It is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this. It might help you:

```
public User createUser(){ 
     Profile p = [select id from profile where name='System Administrator'];
     //userRole r=[SELECT ID FROM userRole WHERE name =: 'CEO']; // Use it if you need Role

     User u = new User(alias = 'salesf', email='iamasalesforce@noemail.com',
                       emailencodingkey='UTF-8',profileid = p.Id,lastname='Testing', Firstname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
                       localesidkey='en_US',country='United States Of America', CompanyName= 'xyz',Phone='(123) 456-7890',title='Dev',PostalCode='S1A 0E5',
                       timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='iamasalesforce@noemail.com'',city='Phoenix',State='Alabama');
     insert u;
     return u;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable workaround. I've adde one more line Task task = [select id, OwnerId from task where OwnerId = '0050Y000001EwVyQAK']; because I need my test to be executed for Task object. But when I run the test I get:  System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject. Is there any workaround and how to avoid such message?

Comment: Please explain what you changed.

Comment: @sfdev hey, seems like ur query is not returning any value. That OwnerId = '0050Y000001EwVyQAK'...seems like tha owner id is wrong. Pls chek the owner id once. Better, u run that siql query first in workbench and see if it returns any result. If u dont know how to use workbench, plz google once. And also, hardcoding is not a good practice. But i will tell u how to avoid it after u have queried the same soql in workbench. Get back to me once done

Answer (score 1):

Profile is read-only. you aren't able to do DML on profile object. It is because Profiles are described as metadata, and are stored as metadata in xml format.