# how to clone a Profile programmatically?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, salesforcedx

How can I clone a salesforce Profile?  I'd prefer to use Apex or DX/CLI.  Our normal process for setting up an Org is to clone standard profiles, and then customize those clones.

This probably happens dozens of times a month, so I'd like to be able to script or automate it.

Comment: I got an error trying to write a Profile, which is consistent with the comments here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185334/dml-not-allowed-on-profile-error-message

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can pragmatically create profiles, I would recommend looking at the potential to use the SOAP api or MetadataAPI with the SOAP API there is a create() callout which could fit the purpose.

Within the Metadata API you have clone() action override which could potentially be leverage to fit the purpose

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm

e.g. to call a clone from apex where clone(preserveId, isDeepClone, preserveReadonlyTimestamps, preserveAutonumber)

```
Account a = new Account(Name=myAccount);
insert a;
Account aClone = a.clone(false,false,false,false);
insert aClone;
```

Comment: Can you give more detail or an example of how to call the clone() method via Apex or DX/CLI?

Comment: @SeanW See above I have added a basic example for you

Comment: I think that Accounts behave differently from Profiles.